# How to set disabled dates on datepicker based on input date?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this code:

```
if (v.name == 'WISH_DATE') {
    const statusDate = moment(this.validAddress.duedate, "DD/MM/YYYY");
    const minDate = moment(statusDate).add(5, 'days');
    let maxDate = moment(statusDate).endOf('month').add(1, 'day');

    v.setup = {
        disableSince: {
            year: maxDate.year(),
            month: minDate.month() + 2,
            day: maxDate.date()
        },
        disableUntil: {
            year: minDate.year(),
            month: minDate.month() + 1,
            day: minDate.date()
        }
    };
}
}
```

So what I want to achieve is this: date is enabled if > status_date+5 and date is enabled `if< last_day_of_month(status_date)+1`

so if I have for example 26/07/2023 I need to enable from 01/08/2023 until end of month, but if its 17/07/2023 then it need to be enabled in next month from 22/07/2023 until end of month. Any suggestion how can I fix it to work? I asked once and that solution works for some dates but now its not working :/

Comment: What is V object here. Is it some kind of library? Also can you explain your example in more detail. What is see is just that date should be enable from 5th day of status date to end of month in both example.

Comment: V object is just list of inputs so when v.name=='WISHDATE' . I am using datepicker component from angular...so it has this proeprties disabled since and disable until...and i need to disabled on date picker those dates based on this calculation